# Decrypting encrypted PHP?

Tags: decryption, encryption, php

I was playing around with a tool I use, and hit a weird error with their wrapper script, so I thought I'd go see what it was doing. Only to discover something I've never seen before. The script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
HR+cPxhDIgFt+4wLvQRVW5p9MLiMxHgCu3AP1OZJo9z0qCcfduiYiA9dMsaq9iVMEU0kU1E6U6On
FcZLsZQlbf3G9ebLMwFP1wITb3gs1l0HcK8UXetSMX70/ITKSO4Hci/Fbwpm6mn3cN9OhNK5s/VD

<Rest omitted since its not my code, but its just a bunch of lines like that>
```

My first guess was base64, then I tried base64+gzip, but it's not that.. Has anyone come across this type of PHP encoding/encryption before? I fixed my problem, but now I'm just curious. What is this weird format, and how is it reversed? I checked a few other scripts, and they all start with `HR+`. I don't see Zend Guard or any other loader modules in php.ini, so I'm stumped on what magic this is.